# VS Codeのツールバー？の名称

Tags: css, vscode

Visual Studio Codeのテーマカラーを変更しています。

このツールバーの正式名称はなんでしょうか？

こちらのドキュメント内にプロパティが定義されていますか？

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color

[image: スクショ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> このツールバーの正式名称はなんでしょうか？

公式ドキュメントの [User Interface](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface) などのページでは名称に関して言及されていませんが、開発者ツールを用いて当該箇所の HTML を読むと、 `aria-label` 属性に **Editor actions**  と書かれています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

> こちらのドキュメント内にプロパティが定義されていますか？

少し読んでみましたが、見当たりませんでした。そのため、ここでは **[Custom CSS and JS Loader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css)** を使用した装飾の変更方法を紹介します。

まず、開発者ツールで装飾を変更したい要素の**選択子を決定**します。そして、それに対して Custom CSS and JS Loader によって**装飾を適用**します。たとえば、 Split Editor Right のアイコンを変更し、アイコンの色を赤色にしたい場合には、以下のように CSS を記述します。この結果として、以下の画像のような動作が得られます。

```css
.codicon-split-horizontal::before {
    color: #ff0000;
    content: "\eb78";
}
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ここで、 editor actions のアイコンや背景色は祖先要素から**継承された値**や**初期値** (透明色) を使用しているため、 [`editorGroupHeader.tabsBackground`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#editor-groups-tabs) のような一部のオプションであれば editor actions に対しても有効である可能性はあります。しかし、それらは editor actions のみに対して適用される装飾ではないため制御しづらく、**複雑な装飾には不向き**だと思います。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]